# iOS system button click frame issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

**Problem:**
  Some system **UIButton Types** are getting clickable outside its defined frame/bounds.

The below two buttons types are getting selected within their defined frame region properly.

```
UIButtonTypeCustom [width:160, height:44.0]
UIButtonTypeSystem [width:50, height:44.0]
```

The below button types are even selectable outside of its frame rectangle from all sides by 10~15points.[Background color is drawn/displaying with in the defined frame for all these buttons]

```
UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,[width:50, height:44.0]
UIButtonTypeInfoLight, [width:50, height:44.0]
UIButtonTypeInfoDark, [width:50, height:44.0]
UIButtonTypeContactAdd [width:50, height:44.0]
```

I expecting the clickable/selectable area should be with in the button frame.

I am creating the buttons using following method:

```
- (UIButton*)createButton:(UIButtonType)style withFrame:(CGRect)frame {

UIButton    *button = nil;
UILabel     *label  =   nil;
switch(style)
{
    case UIButtonTypeCustom: // frame: {x,y,160.0,44.0}
        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 44.0)];
        label.text = @"Custom";
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [button addSubview:label];

        break;

    case UIButtonTypeSystem: // frame: {x,y,50.0,44.0}
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:style];
        [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.frame = frame;
        break;

    default: // frame: {x,y,50.0,44.0}
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:style];
        button.frame = frame;
        break;
}

// Background whitecolor is displaying properly for all buttons.
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return button;
```

}

The **createButton** method is called as below

```
for (int i=0, y=10, x=15; i<6; ++i) {
            if(i == 5)
            {
                y += 90;
                x = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 160.0)/2.0;
            }

            UIButton *btn = [self createButton:5-i withFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, ( i<5 ? 50.0 : 160.0), 44.0)];
            [btn setTag: i+1];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [_subView addSubview:btn];

            x += 60;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS typically expands the touchable area of buttons according to its own internal rules.

My guess: it makes the buttons easier for users to touch.

Comment: I have given them enough frame width & height for selection.
`UIButtonTypeSystem` does have the same width & height and it behaves properly.